# Exercise on expected value, variance and autocovariance function for a stochastic process

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, econometrics, covariance

I need some help in order to solve this exercise for the exam of time-series analysis/econometrics. I am stuck at some points. Here is the exercise:

considering the process ${{y}_{t}}={{\varepsilon }_{t}}{{\varepsilon }_{t-1}}$ with ${{y}_{t}}\tilde{\ }NID(0,{{\sigma }^{2}})$ I have to calculate expected value, variance and autocovariance function. I have already caluculated the expexted value and the variance of the process which are 0 and ${{\sigma }^{4}}$. Now I have to calculate the covariance $Cov({{y}_{t}},{{y}_{t-1}})$. I applied the useual formula and I get $Cov({{y}_{t}},{{y}_{t-1}})=E({{\varepsilon }_{t}}\varepsilon _{t-1}^{2}{{\varepsilon }_{t-2}})$ but then I am unable to go forward and the resut should be 0.

Here there is the second part of the exercise:
considering the transformation ${{z}_{t}}=y_{t}^{2}$ I need to calucalte also for ${{z}_{t}}$ expected value, variance and autocovariance function. For the expected value there was no problem...it is 
${{\sigma }^{4}}$. But then I am stuck with the others:  $V({{z}_{t}})=E[{{(y_{t}^{2})}^{2}}]-E{{[y_{t}^{2}]}^{2}}$ and for the covariance I don't know even where to start...the only hint I have is "if $X\tilde{\ }N(0,{{\sigma }^{2}})\to E[{{X}^{4}}]=3{{\sigma }^{4}}$"

If you can provide me step-by-step calculations it would be very helpful so I can understand which property is involved...I don't need only the final result.

Comment: Thank you for adding the `[self-study]` tag. Please read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Note that we don't provide the final result, we provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Since the unanswered parts of your question are easy to do using the methods normally used to solve the first parts, perhaps you would make progress by reviewing your method to obtain those solutions and considering how to apply it to the rest of the question.

Comment: Yes I know I have to apply the properies of expected value, variance and covariance...but for example in $Cov({{y}_{t}},{{y}_{t-1}})$ there are 3 terms and how I can know if ${{\varepsilon }_{t}}$ and $\varepsilon _{t-1}^{2}$ are independent